# How to generate/pass default sorting explicity in panache query?

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache

There are [`listAll(Sort s)` -like methods](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.quarkus/quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache/latest/io/quarkus/hibernate/orm/panache/PanacheEntityBase.html#findAll()) in PanacheEntity. Suppose I don't want to build `if` statements for all cases (I also need page limits and etc), but wish to compute `s` as if it was omitted.

Is it possible?

How to generate "default" sorting instance of `Sort`? I don't see appropriate construction methods.

Comment: How about `Sort.by` (io.quarkus.panache.common)?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible at the moment, there is an enhancement request on the Quarkus Github repository, you can watch the issue and provides feedback on it: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/6439

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of generic sorting with also a default case built in:

```
   public List<PatientEntity> findByWorkerId(
  Optional<String> sortField, String sortDirection, Long workerId) {
Sort.Direction direction =
    sortDirection.equals("ASC") ? Sort.Direction.Ascending : Sort.Direction.Descending;
PanacheQuery<PatientEntity> patientQuery;
if (sortField.isPresent()) {
  patientQuery = find("workerInCharge.id", Sort.by(sortField.get(), direction), workerId);
} else {
  patientQuery = find("workerInCharge.id",Sort.by("createdTs", direction) ,workerId);
}
return patientQuery.list();
}
```